# Is there an equivalent of $\pm$ but for $\times$ and $\div$?

Tags: notation, arithmetic, binary-operations

Is there mathematical sign that combines multiplication ($\times$) and division ($\div$) operations? Would that ever be used? For example $4({\times}{\div})2$ would give $8$ and $2$, like $4\pm 2$ would give $6$ and $2$.

Comment: When would you ever use this? (Just curious, because I've never seen a case that required this.)

Comment: I don't know to be honest, that's why I'm asking the question. I'm not a professional mathematician, but mathematics is immense field, so maybe there could be practical usage.

Comment: If something appears frequently enough in a field, they will probably devise notation for it. But if it isn't used much in general then there might not be a need for it in general.

Answer (score 12):

I've not seen one, but something one can do is write e.g. $ab^{\pm 1}$ for "$a$ times or divided by $b$".

Answer (score 0):

For the multiplicative equivalent of $\pm$, one can write either $ab^{\pm{1}}$ (as in fish's answer) or $e^{\ln a \pm \ln b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Fish's answer, which I upvoted, is the simplest solution.
Let me just describe another possible notation, in a real context, to answer twosigma's comment.

> Let $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$ be a finite set. Then the elements of
>   the free group over $A$ are products of the form
>   $a_{i_1}^{\epsilon_1} \dotsm a_{i_n}^{\epsilon_n}$, where each
>   $\epsilon_j$ is either $1$ or $-1$.